# An alternative proof: is $f$ is holomorphic and injective, then $f'$ is non-zero.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f:\Omega\to \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic and injective. Then for all $z\in\Omega: f'(z)\not=0$.

This is usually proven (as it is done in the classic Stein & Shakarchi) in a manner that has proven to be confusing to many students. I would like to offer a different, geometric and more intuitive proof here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Prerequisite: winding number

The proof requires the concept of a **winding number**. The winding number $W_{f(\gamma)}(w)$ is the number of times (in $\mathbb{N}$) the image of a curve $\gamma$ goes around a number $w=f(z)$ for some $z\in\Omega$. The formula is easily derived. Consider a parameterization $w=re^{i\theta}$ of $f(\gamma)$, then $$w'=r'e^{i\theta}+i\theta're^{i\theta}$$ and so $$\dfrac{dw}{w}=\dfrac{dr}{r}+id\theta.$$ The complex logarithm is holomorphic so a closed integral of $1/w$ simply equals the change in $\theta=\arg w$. Therefore $$\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{f(\gamma)}\dfrac{dw}{w}=\Delta \arg w =: W_{f(\gamma)}(0).$$ This counts the number of times $f(\gamma)$ goes around the origin. Now it is easily seen with $w=f(z)$ and $w_0=f(z_0)$ that $$W_{f(\gamma)}(z_0) = \dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma}\dfrac{f'(z)}{f'(z)-w_0}dz.$$ From the **argument principle** (see Stein & Shakarchi) we conclude that for a holomorphic function, the number of solutions to $f(z)=w$ is the number of times the image $f(\gamma)$ of a curve $\gamma$ enclosing $z$ goes around $w$, since it basically says that the winding number is the number of zeros of $f-w$ inside $\gamma$.

#### Proof of the theorem

Suppose $f:\Omega\to \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic and injective. We will prove the theorem by contradiction. Assume there is a $z_0\in\Omega$ such that $f'(z_0)\not=0$. Since $f$ is holomorphic, so too is $f'$ ($f$ is analytic), so the zeros of $f'$ on $\Omega$ are isolated. Choose a disk $D\subseteq \Omega$ centered at $z_0$, small enough, such that $f'$ is only zero at $z_0$ in the disk. Then $f$ has a power series in this disk such that for all $z\in D$ $$f(z)-f(z_0) = (z-z_0)^kH(z)$$ where $k\geq 2$ ($k>2$ iff $f''(z_0)=0$ and so on), $H(z_0)\not=0$ and $H$ holomorphic on $D$.

Call $w_0=f(z_0)$. Then, using $(f/g)'=f'/f+g'/g$: $$W_{f(\partial D)}(z_0)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\partial D}\dfrac{k}{z-z_0}dz+\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\partial D}\dfrac{H'(z)}{H(z)}dz=k.$$

So the number of times $f$ maps $z_0$ to $w_0$ is $k$ i.e $k$ is the multiplicity of the zero in $f-w_0$. Now choose a $w$ close to $w_0$ such that it is still inside $f(\gamma)$ and so that $f(\gamma)$ goes around $w$ the same number of times as it goes around $w_0$. Then $f$ also maps $k$ points from inside $D$ to $w$. In general these need not be distinct, but in this case they are. Indeed, we chose $D$ small enough so that $f'$ is non-zero for all $w\not=z_0$. Then, the power series of $f$ around $w$ looks like $f(z)=f(w) + f'(w)(z-w)+G(z)$. Therefore, each $z$ that is mapped to $0$ by $f-w$ has multiplicity one. So there are $k$ (which is at least two) distinct points inside $D$ that get mapped to this $w$, which contradicts the injectivity of $f$.

Comment: Note that from the power series of $f$ around $z_0$ we can conclude that $H$ is non-zero on $\partial D$ by simply looking at the modulus. $H(z)=0$ for some $z\in\partial D$ would give a contradiction. Also note that $W_{f(\gamma)}(z_0)=W_{(f-w_0)(\gamma)}(0)$.